# Why do they clone the entire model before training in torch?

Tags: lua, neural-network, torch

I have been going through lots of Torch code recently. I have been noticing, usually after the model is constructed, it is cloned, like in following code :

```
siamese_1=siamese_1:cuda()
parameters,gradParameters = siamese_1:getParameters()
siamese_2=siamese_1:clone('weight','bias','gradWeight','gradBias')
siamese_net:add(siamese_1)
siamese_net:add(siamese_2)
```

`siamese_1` being a constructed model.

It is difficult to understand why is this being done ?

This code is for performing fine-tuning over networks. Is from the [this](https://github.com/kkanshul/End-to-End-Localization-and-Ranking-for-Relative-Attributes/blob/2d09b117dca0fbe09c36688e93a42859138b2e9a/construct_network.lua) repository (line 122 to 126).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you clone a model and specify some additional arguments (like `'weight`, etc) the new model will share these parameters with the original one. Thus in your case the models `siamese_1` and `siamese_2` share their weights, bias and the corresponding gradients.

In the code you are looking at the authors want to create a network with two parallel networks sharing their weights, this is the reason why they use the `clone` function.

Comment: In this code the network parallelism is already done above the mentioned lines.

I do understand that the parameters are clone onto another module (`siamese_2`) but why is then `siamese_1` also added to `siamese_net` ?

Comment: no, the lines 122 to 126 do the parallelism. `siamese_net` is a `ParallelTable` and consequently you need to add at least 2 modules (in parallel) to this network. This is why you add both `siamese_1` and `siamese_2`, which are consequently put in parallel in the `siamese_net` network.

Comment: True, also I found out the parallel networks are needed because this implementation tries to pass two data tensors at that the same time.